# Copy, paste and moving

Tags: edit-mode

Suppose that I have 2 identical objects created by copy and paste. How do I move one and left the other
stay at its position ? What are the hot-keys for this and clicking options in the Blender's workspace ?

[image]

Comment: you want to move one and leave the other where it is?

Comment: @RBlong2us Yes, exactly.

Comment: are they separate objects?

Comment: @RBlong2us  Yes, but they do not move at all. I can just rotate them by pressing the mouse's wheel. How do I move one and both ? Thank you for your patience.

Comment: press g to move the selected object(s)

Comment: you can type in a number amount to move them a certain distance, and you can type in x,y, or z to specify the axis.  Thought I'd specify that if you didn't know.

Comment: does this work?

Comment: @RBlong2us Yes, "g" is the key thing here. Thank you.

Comment: @RBlong2us Can you please have a look at [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/182911/edited-picture-setting-to-new-color) ?

Comment: sure, I'll look at it now

Comment: @RBlong2us Thank you. And yet: please see my new comment below your answer I got stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to move an object with a key shortcut, **press G** to move the selected object(s).  If you choose to cancel movement before you hit enter or click **LMB**, you can click **RMB** to cancel the movement.  You can choose to move it just by moving the mouse, but you can also choose an axis by pressing x, y, or z after pressing "g".

If you want it to **not** move on a specific axis, then press Shift-(axis).  For instance, if you don't want it to move up or down, press Shift-Z.

After pressing G, you can just move it a certain distance with your mouse.  However, if you want to move it an exact distance, you can type in an amount **after pressing G**.  You can also backspace, so you don't have to try al over again.  Also, you press the **- symbol** to change the value you typed to a negative amount so it will travel backwards along the axis.  The negative symbol switches the current amount's symbol, so if you hit **-** when the amount is set to a negative amount, it will change to a positive amount.  Try this out to fully understand.

One more thing: It doesn't matter if you specify distance before choosing the axis you are moving on.  You can even change amounts and change axis in-between each other, if that makes sense.  The only important thing is that you press G before choosing distance or axis.

Please ask if any of this doesn't make sense.