# Edited picture-setting to new color

Tags: node-editor, edit-mode, color

I have edited with Ctrl+left mouse click a small area of pixels (see the snippet below)
which yielded the small dark rectangle in the l.h.s. half of the blue bottom picture.
Now I wanna to set this to white color. How shall I proceed ? I have also added the "Mask.001"
node but it seems to have no effect to the output. (Perhaps I have weight 1 on the other
layer picture and I have to change this somehow).

[image]

**EDIT**

[image]

**EDIT2**
[image]

Comment: Use the mask as fac to control the mix of the image and color you want. .

Comment: @susu Please see my **EDIT**. What's wrong with it? I have added Mask to Fac, but it's still black. I've also set the Color field but I do not know where to set my new color-it has no field for this.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that your mask is not the correct size for your image, and you need to change the Mix Node settings from "Color" to "Mix".

You need to change the settings for your mask node to "Fixed" instead of "Scene Size."  Then, type in the x/y dimensions of your image.  I also changed the mix node to "Mix" instead of "Color."

[image: Fixed]

If you don't know how to find the dimension of your image, open it on Windows Explorer, right-click on it, and press "Properties."  You can find the dimensions under the "Details" tab.

Hope that fixes your problem!  Let me know if you have any other issues.

Comment: Please I'm trying your advice. But I need a basic advice: how do I add the bottom picture with yellow dots to a mask above. I.e. how do I cretae "mask" in the first work area What's the HOTKEY?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you are asking.  Did my result answer your question?  If so, what result do you want to make now?  If you could explain what the final result should  be, I may be able to fully understand what your asking.

Comment: I need a HotKey (or) for the very bottom rectangle of my Workspace, i.e. one with the picture with Yellow edited dots: the entire separate bottom workspace. Please, is it clear now ?

Comment: So, you want a HotKey that will open/close the window in your workspace that holds the blue picture with yellow dots?  Or are you trying to add that picture as a mask or something?